# logic app, 403 if try to connect to storage behind firewall

Tags: azure-storage, azure-logic-apps

i deployed a logic app standard to use vnet integration. In our scenario we want to get attachment from an email and store it to a storage account type datalake. We are using following connectors:

Office 365 and
Azure blob Storage

the problem is that our storage are behind firewall and private endpoint. If storage account are in all network flow work but not work if it is under firewall and we got 403(logic app although is under vnet integration, pass over internet as i can see on log analytics).

i also following microsoft doc and also this link without success:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure/deploying-standard-logic-app-to-storage-account-behind-firewall/ba-p/2626286

i also tried this and works:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support&tabs=single-tenant#access-blob-storage-with-managed-identities
but i got file corrupted E.g. body of other connector if is a csv or if attachment is an excel file is corrupted. here the flow via https:

[image]
[image]
[image]

There is a way to use vnet integration and storage private endpoint or there is a way to take the attachment and save it as-is via https connector? (independently by file extension)?

Answer (score 0):

Standard Logic app with private end point, cannot access the storage account with private end point. Storage account can be used as storage for logic app. But accessing the storage account and files from Logic app is not possible, if both resources are in same region.

To achieve this, we need to create Logic app and storage in 2 different region and whitelist the Ip. Refer the below link

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/access-azure-blob-using-logic-app/ba-p/1451573